# Logging request body in json?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, log4j

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<?> getCall(@Valid @RequestBody Request request) {
    String requestJson = null;
    try {
        requestJson = ObjectMapperUtil.writeValueAsString(request);
        log.info(requestJson) // will this introduce latency in my api.
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getData(request));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(requestJson);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(Request.builder().errors(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)).build());
    }

}
```

Just want to know that if we print the request body in json format after converting using ObjectMapper, what will be the impact on the latency on the api. Should we go ahead with @toString logging only. What's the good trade-off here.

Comment: it depends on where your log will be written - console, file or somewhere else and also it depends on size of your object.  Which logging system do you use? What is your purpose to log object?

Comment: Logs gets printed on the console. Jackson's ObjectMapper is being used for conversion. the purpose of log object is to take the objects from the central repo and retry using that request is there comes some issue in prod.

Comment: Could you add a Request object class also to question, is Request has some sensitive data (which should not be showed). Just to clarify do you care about extra latency for `log.info(requestJson)` line? Where do you log this info?(remote server/file/console?)

Comment: Request data does not contain any sensitive data, Headers do contain it (thus we are not logging them), request gets logged in containers in console which is deployed on EKS. Also there's a agent that runs and fetches the logs from console and sends them to central logging system coralogix , so that should not slow down anything ideally. We do care about latency if the latency of api is already high

Comment: What logging API are you using? Log4j2 API supports logging `Object`s and the configured layout decides how to serialize it to a `String` (cf. e.g. [JSON Template Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html)). The advantage of logging objects is that serialization occurs only if the logger is enabled. There will always be a serialization overhead, but you can enable/disable it through a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about latency, add an if statement around that code (most logging frameworks have such check methods):

```java
String requestJson = null;
try {
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        requestJson = ObjectMapperUtil.writeValueAsString(request);
        log.info(requestJson);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getData(request));
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (requestJson != null) {
        log.error(requestJson, e);
    } else {
        log.error("Failed to convert '{}' to JSON", request, e);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(Request.builder().errors(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)).build());
}
```

Note that if the conversion of the object to JSON fails, `requestJson` will remain `null`, and there's no point in logging it. I also didn't add a check for `log.isErrorEnabled()` because a) that's almost always the case, and b) there's no logic involved in the error logging; any filtering will be done by the logger itself. Also note that I included the exception in the logging as well - you really want to know *why* the failure occurred.

There will still be latency, but only if needed. You can also consider moving the conversion into the catch (which needs its own try-catch). That way, the request JSON will only be logged if there's an error.